# Absolute positioning and float left/right

Tags: css, css-float, css-position

This is apparently contradictory. What I need is to have two child elements positioned at the left and right edges of the parent element while vertically centered and overlaid over all other sibling elements.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `left` and `right` for that.

```
.child
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
}

.child .left
{
    left: 0;
}

.child .right
{
    right: 0;
}
```

The `top: 50%` will align the top edge of the child to halfway down the parent. If your parent has a constant size, use pixel sizing. Otherwise you'll probably need some javascript to get it exactly right.

**edit in response to comment:**

To make it relative to the parent instead of the page, you need to give the parent `position: relative;` and it will work. The default position is `static` and that won't work for this.

Comment: If you simply set everything with % size, you just use math to add up to 100...see my example

Answer (score 0):

If I undestand correctly:

```
<div class="parent" style="position:absolute;height:70%;width:70%;top:15%;left:15%;background-color:#eee;border:solid blue 1px;">
    <div class="left" style="position:absolute;width:30%;height:70%;top:15%;left:0%;background-color:black;z-index:20;">left box vertically aligned</div>

    <div class="right" style="position:absolute;width:30%;height:70%;top:15%;left:70%;background-color:black;z-index:20;">right box vertically aligned</div>
</div>​
```

see : http://jsfiddle.net/dankpiff/zmYEf/

If you set the elements underneath with a lower z-index they will be covered by the 'left' and 'right' boxes

Is this what you mean?

Comment: You use widths 30%, 70%, and 30% for the left, middle, and right. That adds up to more than 100%...

Comment: There is no middle. Read it again, or click the jsfiddle link

Comment: I can't set anything by %, it's absolute in pixels

Comment: @DankPiff: Ah, I see now. It wasn't indented when I first read it, so I thought it was just three `<div>`s.